# Checking if time-delta value is in range past midnight

Tags: python, time, compare, timedelta

So if I have two timedelta values such as `21:00:00`(PM) as start time and `03:00:00` (AM) as end time and I wish to compare `23:00:00` within this range, to see whether it falls between these two, without having the date value, how could I do so?

So although in this example it will see `23:00:00` larger than `21:00:00` it will not see `23:00:00` less than `03:00:00`, which is my issue. I need to be able to compare time on a 24 hour circle using timedelta or a conversion away from timedelta is fine.

**Note:** The start/end time ranges can change, so any could be AM/PM. So I cannot just add a day to the end time for example.

Comment: Check whether diff(23, 21) is lesser than diff(23, 3)?

Comment: Is the end time guaranteed to be within 24 hours of the start time? If not, it can get complicated. If the start time is Monday at 11pm and the end time is Wednesday at 3am, then an arbitrary time say 11am falls between them, as long as you are talking about 11am Tuesday. If this is a possibility, you will need something more than just the start and end hours.

Comment: @DavidJenkins yes, it will only be within a 24 hour period, all the time. So when you pick any arbitrary time i.e. 3pm but your range (subject to change) is saying only 6am to 12pm, this should not be in range.

Answer (score 0):

You should probably think about using `datetime.time` instead of `datetime.timedelta` for absolute times. Nonetheless here's something that should work given your existing situation.

```
def is_in_time_range(start, end, time):
    if end < start:
        return start < time or end > time
    return start < time < end


from datetime import timedelta

>>> is_in_time_range(timedelta(hours=21), timedelta(hours=3), timedelta(hours=23))
True
>>> is_in_time_range(timedelta(hours=21), timedelta(hours=3), timedelta(hours=4))
False
>>> is_in_time_range(timedelta(hours=21), timedelta(hours=3), timedelta(hours=2))
True
```

Should you decide to use `datetime.time` instead as I've suggested, this solution still works:

```
from datetime import time
>>> is_in_time_range(time(hour=21), time(hour=3), time(hour=23))
True
>>> is_in_time_range(time(hour=21), time(hour=3), time(hour=4))
False
>>> is_in_time_range(time(hour=21), time(hour=3), time(hour=2))
True
```

Answer (score 0):

It becomes "difficult" only when endtime is smaller than starttime (IE, next day). But, you could have a test, if this is the case, add 12 hours to all three items, so now you can easily test and verify that 11am is between 9am and 3pm.